# Get nodes which are not connected to specific node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all the nodes which are not connected to the given set of nodes. Suppose I've 5 nodes A,B,C,D,E. Now A->B->C are connected with the `:Is_Friend` relationship. Now I want all the nodes which are not connected to A (i.e D and E).

I tried this query but it's not working

```
MATCH (a:Friend{name:"A"})-[:Is_Friend_Of*]->(b:Friend) 
MATCH (c:Friend) 
WHERE NOT (c)-[:Is_Friend_Of]->(b)
RETURN c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thi query should do what you want it to, however, I would caution that depending on the size of the number of unmatched friends in your database you could get a lot of matches.

```
// match the single longest chain of friends in a :Is_Friend_Of relationship
// starting with 'A' that is possible
MATCH path=(a:Friend {name:"A"})-[:Is_Friend_Of*]->(b:Friend)
WHERE NOT (b)-[:Is_Friend_Of*]->()
WITH path

// then find the other friends that aren't in that path
MATCH (c:Friend) 
WHERE NOT c IN nodes(path)
RETURN c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
match(a:Friend {name: "A"})-[:Is_Friend_Of*]-(b)
with collect(distinct b) as all_connected_to_a
match(n:Friend) where not n in all_connected_to_a return n;
```

It firstly gets a uniqued collection of all nodes connected to `(a:Friend {name: "A"})` (including node a, because the pattern `-[:Is-Friend_Of*]-` is not directional).
Then it returns all nodes which are not in that collection i.e. they are not connected to `(a:Friend {name: "A"})` through relationship of type `:Is_Friend_Of`.